# Should I use 'neither one', 'none of them' or 'neither one of them' in this question?

Tags: ellipsis, phrase-choice

I'd like to form this question:

> Is she beautiful or smart or {neither one/ neither one of them/none of them}?

So do I need 'of them' for sure or can I omit 'of them' and say 'neither one' or only 'neither'? I'd like to keep it simplest possible.

Which one is correct?

1. Is she beautiful or smart or **neither one**?
2. Is she beautiful or smart or **neither one of them**?
3. Is she beautiful or smart or **none of them**?
4. Is she beautiful or smart or **neither**?
5. Is she beautiful or smart or **none**?

The duplicate question does not answer my question. My question is not about single plural verb harmony. It is about whether I can omit and if so to what extent I can omit to give the same meaning in simplest way and that according to what one prefers neither over none or vice versa.

Comment: Please, give a sentence or a situation  to make it clear. How are you going to use them?

Comment: is she beautiful or smart or neither one/ neither one of them/none of them? so do I need "of them" for sure?

Comment: Pls edit you question with additional information. Comments are temporary...

Comment: Is it this or that or neither?

Comment: @StoneyB so that s exactly my question. can I leave out "one of them" and only say neither or none? secondly if I decide to append "one of them" none of them or neither of them should be preferred? why?

Comment: I edited your question a little bit to make it a little more clear what you're asking and voted to re-open. You may say "Is he handsome or smart or neither?" and leave out the "one/one of them" entirely when using neither.

Comment: can I say as well " is he handsome or smart or none"?  secondly is i use one of them would you prefere neither or nor? also thirdly can I omit one and use "neither of them" and " none of them"

Comment: I edited and added detail as per your suggestion @ColleenV now I should only wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying trying to convey the message in the simplest way possible, regardless of grammaticality. So, my response relies on what I think sounds natural. Also, I assume that you want to keep this specific

> Is she beautiful or smart or X?

structure.

---

I assume that there is a woman and you are interested in two particular traits, being beautiful and being smart. There three options and only one can be chosen:

- beautiful
- smart
- not beautiful and not smart

Your 1. expresses the scenario, but *neither one* seems redundant since the question is brief. In my opinion, you don't need the word *one*.

If your 1. is redundant, then your 2. is definitely redundant. It still expresses the scenario, but "one of them" is excessive. Again, I am assuming that you want the simplest answer. In this instance, I am taking simple to mean terse.

Your 3. doesn't sound right. To me, *of them* suggests that there are more than two traits up for consideration. *None* also suggest to me that there are more than two traits up for consideration. So *none of them* strongly suggests that to me.

As you can imagine, I like 4. best. Regardless of whether we use the word *neither* correctly or not, we understand that it is to be used with **two** things. Because of this strong association with two things, I think it is natural to use *neither* here. In this instance, *neither* implies exactly "not trait one nor trait two".

I don't like *none* in 5. Again, *none* suggests use with more than two things to me, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

To me: 1. and 2. have the same meaning and are used when talking about **two** persons.

> Where are your parents?
> I don't know, **neither one** is home right now.
>
> **Neither one of** my parents is home right now.

3. Has the same meaning but can also be used to talk about **more than two** persons.

> **None of** my parents are home right now.
>   **None of** my 10 friends showed up for my birthday.

Even though the first one (none of my parents) sounds weird and I would prefer not using it.

Comment: I edited my question for more clarity, I think your answer is little off to what I ask and I tried to fix the ambiguity in my question maybe you can also edit your answer.

Comment: @CeyhunÖzsoylu: Applying what I said: you have two options (this or that), so you can use 2. and 3. You can't use 1. because you need to keep **of them** to remind the reader of the two choices.

Comment: is she beautiful or smart or neither one/ neither one of them/none of them? so do I need "of them" for sure? if yes neither one of them or none of them, which one sounds better and why?

Answer (score 0):

All of your doubts will be cleared by going [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-and-negative-sentences/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either).

To me, only 1, 2 and 4 make sense.

Actually, you can consider 1 = 2 = 4.

Neither is used when we're given two things and none, when multiple of them are given.

We can never use statements 3 and 4. They are incorrect. We are considering a girl's beauty and smartness (***TWO*** things), use of "none" is inappropriate here.